# Whats the best way to iterate a list if you are destroying its contents as you go

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I have a list of objects that I want to remove each element in turn which changes the length of the list as it goes so basically doesn't work. It's hard to explain so I'll just show the code:

```
public List<GameObject> ActiveChunks = new List<GameObject>();

public static void DeActivate(GameObject Obj)
{
    //Do lots of other stuff based on the Obj
    ....
    ....
    instance.ActiveChunks.Remove(Obj);
 }

public static void DeActivateAllChunks()
{
    for (int c = 0; c < instance.ActiveChunks.Count; c++)
    {
        DeActivate(instance.ActiveChunks[c], false);
    }
 }
```

As you can see the for loop goes through my active chunks list calling a deactivate function which does some stuff on the object and then removes the
item from the list. My question is, is there a better way to iterate through a List that is being modified?

Comment: You need to make a copy of your list and remove items from the copy

Comment: Iterate from count to 0 with `--`?

Comment: I think you'll get errors removing from a list as you iterate through it forwards like that. You need to go backwards `for (var c = instance.ActiveChunks.Count - 1; c >= 0; c--)`

Comment: You could use a [Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pop each item from it in a `while` loop until it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1)** You can store the list into a new variable and loop the original list and then remove the items in the temp variable . At last use the temp variable.

```
public List<GameObject> ActiveChunks = new List<GameObject>();
var tempActiveChunks = ActiveChunks; //temp variable

public static void DeActivate(GameObject Obj)
{
    //Do lots of other stuff based on the Obj
    ....
    ....
    tempActiveChunks.Remove(Obj);
 }

public static void DeActivateAllChunks()
{
    for (int c = 0; c < instance.ActiveChunks.Count; c++)
    {
        DeActivate(instance.ActiveChunks[c], false);
    }
    instance.ActiveChunks = tempActiveChunks;
 }
```

---

**Option 2)** Also you can iterate from backwards like below

```
public static void DeActivateAllChunks()
{
    for (int c = instance.ActiveChunks.Count - 1; c >=0 ; c--)
    {
        DeActivate(instance.ActiveChunks[c], false);
    }
 }
```

---

**Option 3** Thanks to  [**Sac**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1659563/sac), You can copy the List into a temp variable and then iterate over the temp variable and remove the item from the actual list.

```
    public List<GameObject> ActiveChunks = new List<GameObject>();
    var tempActiveChunks = ActiveChunks; //temp variable

    public static void DeActivate(GameObject Obj)
    {
        //Do lots of other stuff based on the Obj
        ....
        ....
        instance.ActiveChunks.Remove(Obj);
     }

    public static void DeActivateAllChunks()
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < tempActiveChunks.Count; c++)
        {
            DeActivate(instance.ActiveChunks[c], false);
        }            
     }
```

Comment: If I were you then I will copy `ActiveChunks` and loop through that copied list while removing from `ActiveChunks`..

Comment: @Sac Added your suggestion too into answer thanks, Yes  that seems to be the right way, But out of interest is there any performance issue with the 1st option approach?

Comment: Thanks everyone, all good suggestions. This is used in a frame update in a game so I will go with the going backwards through the list as I'm not sure of the performance cost of making a copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through them backwards:

```
public static void DeActivateAllChunks()
{
    for (int c = instance.ActiveChunks.Count - 1; c >=0 ; c--)
    {
        DeActivate(instance.ActiveChunks[c], false);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to count backwards rather than forwards. That way the deletion / destruction doesn't effect the next row you're going to get.

```
for (int c = instance.ActiveChunks.Count - 1; c >= 0; c--)
{
    DeActivate(instance.ActiveChunks[c], false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need for loop and additional index variable. The following approach is better:

```
while(ActiveChunks.Count > 0) {
    var theLastIndex = ActiveChunks.Count - 1;
    var temp = ActiveChunks[theLastIndex];
    ActiveChunks.RemoveAt(theLastIndex);
    // deactivate object removed from the list 
    DeActivate(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the flexible way, try out this

```
 public  static List<GameObject> ActiveChunks = new List<GameObject>();

        public static bool DeActivate(GameObject Obj)
        {
            if(true)//your condition
            {
                return true;//do not remove the object
            }
            else
            {
                return false;//remove the object
            }
        }

        public static void DeActivateAllChunks()
        {
            ActiveChunks = ActiveChunks.Where(c => DeActivate(c)).ToList();
        }
```